# Creating database schema from DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Is it possible, without writing any SQL or using any 3rd party libraries to create a database schema from several ADO.NET `DataTable`s?

Comment: Ultimately you will have to execute a CREATE TABLE statement, dont you think? You can create a class that encapsulates the process using metadata from the DataTable, of course.

Comment: I would not like to write any SQL.

Comment: How do you expect any table(s) to be created then? I think essentially your question should be -- "Does the .NET Framework come with any functions that automatically create an sql table from a DataTable?" To which the answer is no, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how "not sql" this is, but you can use [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162575.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to make a function that writes the SQL for you. However if you don't want to use SQL at all I would think you're out of luck:

```
    private string GetSqlCommand(Dictionary<string, Type> schema, string tableName, bool includeIdentity)
    {
        string sql = "CREATE TABLE [" + tableName + "] (\n";

        if (includeIdentity)
            sql += "[ID] int not null Identity(1,1) primary key,\n";

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Type> info in schema)
        {
            sql += "[" + info.Key + "] " + SQLGetType(info.Value) + ",\n";
        }

        sql = sql.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',', '\n' }) + "\n";

        return sql + ")";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
SqlConnection con = connection string;
        con.Open();
        string sql = "Create Table abcd (";
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            sql += "[" + column.ColumnName + "] " + "nvarchar(50)" + ",";
        }
        sql = sql.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) + ")";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.close();
```

I am giving a predefined table-name abcd.